# Which headers to include in Tensorflow load graph c++ example?

Tags: c++, graph, header, tensorflow

The c++ API for Tensorflow looks simple enough, but I cannot figure out which header files are needed to run the shown example on their page:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/cc/index.html

And if I get it working, will this API allow me to do classification with a neural net I built in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the headers I would assume some subset of these:

```
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/graph/default_device.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/graph/graph_def_builder.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/core/threadpool.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/strings/stringprintf.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/init_main.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/logging.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/types.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
```

From https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc